# Using sumif by row in an arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

I've got a sumif at the start of every row of my data adding up numbers if they are >0 and another doing the same for numbers <0 like this:

```
=SUMIF(P6:X6;">0")
```

This works and all but it's quite a pain to drag the cel down every time I add more data. Is there a way for me to turn this into a `ARRAYFORMULA` that just keeps going down.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for sums ">0" is:

```
=arrayformula(mmult(A2:C*--(A2:C>0), transpose(A2:C2 * 0 + 1)))
```

and for sums "<0":

```
=arrayformula(mmult(A2:C*--(A2:C<0), transpose(A2:C2 * 0 + 1)))
```

[image]

---

`transpose(A2:C2 * 0 + 1))` is an array of 1: `[1, 1, 1, ...]` It's the part of [`mmult`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292?hl=en) function to convert the result into row.

`--(A2:C>0)` double minus is for converting booleans into 1 (if `true`) and 0 (if `false`)